# Element Align Problem - Negative margins, images etc

Tags: html, css, margin, alignment

I'm trying to make a header that goes outside the borders of my sidebar and has a shadow image that makes it look like it is a book-mark.

Something similar to this: http://inelmo.com/images/img2.png

Right now I tried my best, but it is not looking correct. here is my code for sidebar and header That I think should work to make this effect, but it isn't.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Sidebar -->
<aside id="sidebar">

   <!-- header div -->
   <div id="sideProfile">

      <!-- Span with image background -->
      <span id="sideHshadow"></span>

   </div>

</aside>
```

**CSS**

```
#sidebar {
        padding: 15px;
        width: 400px;
}

/*Span with shadow image to make it look like a bookmark */
#SideHshadow {
height: 6px;
width: 12px;
margin: 0 0 -6px 0;
float: right;
background: url("../images/sidebar_header_shadow.png") no-repeat;
}

#sideProfile {
background:#333333;
border-bottom: 1px solid #2d2d2d;
height: 50px;
width: 400px;
margin: 0 -12px 0 0;

box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #77bee6;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #77bee6;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #77bee6;

-webkit-border-radius: 7px 7px 0 7px;
-khtml-border-radius: 7px 7px 0 7px;
-moz-border-radius: 7px 7px 0 7px;
border-radius: 7px 7px 0 7px;


}
```

Anyone knows how to make it look like in example? Thnx

Here is the #sideHshadow background image file: http://inelmo.com/images/sidebar_header_shadow.png

Comment: are you using the correct html5 doctype? also, does your browser support the aside element?

Comment: Yes I'm using correct !doctype and modern browsers + html5 support for IE9 is included, I'm pretty confident that this are not what's causing the issue, but I can't figure out why this isn't working how intended, could it be padding of #sidebar? not sure ...

Comment: uh... we don't have the image file?  it's very hard to work on something like this without all the pieces ;)

Comment: Are you talking about "../images/sidebar_header_shadow.png" it's just a small image that goes on the right under #sideProfile div that makes this effect, it's nothing big just small image ))) here is the image
http://inelmo.com/images/sidebar_header_shadow.png

Comment: Oh just in case, in this example http://inelmo.com/images/img2.png that image is on the left, but in my case it is on the right ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pure CSS version: http://jsfiddle.net/bcZKh/2/

Code below:

```
<div id="list">
    <div class="item selected">Nationwide Coverage Area</div>
    <div class="shadow"></div>
</div>
```

```
body {margin:40px}
#list {width:200px;border-radius:8px;min-height:200px;background:#E6E5E0;padding:20px 0;position:relative}
.item {color:#fff;font-size:0.8em;line-height:24px;font-family:sans-serif;text-indent:24px;margin-right:-12px;margin-left:-12px;position:relative;z-index:1}
.item.selected {background:#C74312;border-radius:4px;border-bottom-left-radius:0}
.shadow {border-color:transparent #733411 transparent transparent;border-width:12px;border-style:solid;height:0;width:0;position:absolute;top:32px;left:-24px;z-index:0}
```